# CheckBox to duplicate all completed input fields to ones below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code. `OnClick` the checkbox, I would like to duplicate each complete `input` to the ones below.

I'm able to do this with a long `Jquery` script. But there must be a way to do this with a couple of lines? Would someone please mind explaining the concept?

Here is the <kbd>**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLz5wbe1/1/)**</kbd>:

And my code:

```
<form action="?action=processOrder" method="post" id="hidden">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="Cash on Delivery" checked>
        <p style="float: left;margin: -2px 0 0 9px;">Cash on Delivery</p>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="Pay Online" id="payOnline">
        <p style="float: left;margin: -2px 0 0 9px;">Pay Online</p>
    </label>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input id="deliveryAddressLineOne" type="text" name="deliveryAddressLineOne" placeholder="Address line one" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input id="deliveryAddressLineTwo" type="text" name="deliveryAddressLineTwo" placeholder="Address line two" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input id="deliveryAddressTown" type="text" name="deliveryAddressTown" placeholder="Town" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input id="deliveryAddressCounty" type="text" name="deliveryAddressCounty" placeholder="County" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input id="deliveryAddressPostCode" type="text" name="deliveryAddressPostCode" placeholder="Post Code" required>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- if pay online checked, show the other fields -->
    <label class="billingAddress" style="display:none;">My billing address is the same as delivery.
        <input type="checkBox" placeholder="Same as Delivery" id="duplicateDelivery">
    </label>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" name="billingAddressLineOne" placeholder="Address line one" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" name="billingAddressLineTwo" placeholder="Address line two" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" name="billingAddressTown" placeholder="Town" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" name="billingAddressCounty" placeholder="County" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="contact-inputs">
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" name="billingAddressPostCode" placeholder="Post Code" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input id="processOrder" class="green-button" type="submit" name="saveChanges" value="Process Order" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the `jQuery`,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'payOnline') {
            $('.billingAddress').show();
            $('#County').show();
            $('#postCode').show();
            $("input").prop('required', 'true');

    } else {

        $('#processOrder').show();
        $('.billingAddress').hide();
        $('#County').hide();
        $('#postCode').hide();
        $("input").prop('required', false);

    }
});
});`
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you intentionally only showing `processOrder` and never hiding it? Seems inconsistent with the rest of the code you've written.

Comment: This Fiddle is not working. It does not include the jquery code

Comment: @DeeMac the processOrder is always show as it redirects to a page that allows the user to confirm/edit the supplied details and their user details they registered with. There is a switch in my php that checks what radio is checked and then carrys out the required action on such. Would love to hear if you think think there is a better way?

KaustavBanerjee I have updated the fiddle, not sure why it didnt include the jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `toggle()` method, with a Boolean switch:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    var check = this.id === 'payOnline';
    // select all the elements you want to show/hide:
    $('.billingAddress, #County, #postCode')
        // using a Boolean switch will show the collection
        // if it is, or evaluates to, true (or truthy) and
        // hide them if it is, or evaluates to, false (or falsey):
        .toggle(check);
    if (!check) {
        // this is in an 'if' because you've only shown one state,
        // though I suspect that's an error by omission, and
        // toggle(!check) is more likely what you want:
        $('#processOrder').show();
    }
    $('input').prop('required', check);
});
```

Although it's worth noting that your final selector will disable *all* `<input>` elements, including the radio-button you're binding the `click` event-handler to.

References:

- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Nice! Didn't think of comma separating the selectors.

Comment: Be careful though - you've missed out `$('#processOrder')` (gets shown if not `payOnline` - but never hidden).

Comment: thanks David, as DeeMac mentioned I hadnt though of comma seperating the selectors. Great!!

Say the user filled out the deliverAddress inputs, how would I then copy these values to the BillingAddress inputs if the checkbox #duplicateDelivery is cheked? Should update my original question to make more clear.